# Split text and save to different fields(No duplicate, With Duplicate) Using Array in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see in the picture below, I have Current Output and Expected output. The First thing is that I  have worksheet `SPLIT` and `Duplication.`
What I want is for `TextBox1` to be filled and entered by the user. It will be  saved to a different column the `No Duplicated Word` and `With Duplicated Word`

In this picture, in the `current output` at the `first input` all insertion of data looks well. But in the `2nd input` of data everything was failed. How can I do this with this code? In the expected output the shown picture says that it removes the duplicate word and saves it, but still the `financial word is not missing`.

Code

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim WArray As Variant
    Dim TextString As String
    Dim col_no_dup As Long
    Dim col_dup As Long
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim sht_database As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sht_database = .Sheets("Duplication")
        TextString = LCase(TextBox1)
    End With

    WArray = Split(TextString, " ") 'load array

    If (TextString = "") Then
        MsgBox ("Error: Pls Enter your data")
    End
    Else: End If

    'set column locations for duplicates/no duplicates
    col_no_dup = 1
    col_dup = 2

    With sht_database
    'Print whole array into duplicates column
    .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count,col_dup).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Resize(UBound(WArray)+ IIf(LBound(WArray) = 0, 1, 0)) = Application.Transpose(WArray)

    'Loop through array
    For i = LBound(WArray) To UBound(WArray)
        counter = 0
        lrow_no_dup = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, col_no_dup).End(xlUp).row
        For n = 1 To lrow_no_dup 'loop through and check each existing value in the no dup column
            If .Cells(n, col_no_dup).Value = WArray(i) Then
                counter = counter + 1 'account for each occurence
            Else: End If
        Next n
        If counter = 0 Then 'counter = 0 implies the value doesn't exist in the "No Duplicates" column
            .Cells(lrow_no_dup + 1, col_no_dup).Value = WArray(i)
        Else: End If
    Next i

    End With

    MsgBox ("Successfully inserted")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call SplitText
End Sub
```

**Current output**
[image: Current output]
 **Expected output**
[image: expected output]

Comment: Pls refresh the page to i updated the expected output. because i uploaded the wrong picture

Comment: The second textbox also takes into account the values of your first list. Best to put those in column 3 and 4 instead of below each other.

Comment: You mean sir you're suggesting to append those data column per column each word that is splitted not rows by rows?

Comment: No. Put the data from textbox 1 to column 1 and 2. Put data from textbox 2 to column 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead. Your vba is looping through the entire range. Where as what I think you want to do is loop through only

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim WArray As Variant
    Dim TextString As String
    Dim col_no_dup As Long
    Dim col_dup As Long
    Dim counter As Boolean
    Dim sht_database As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sht_database = .Sheets("Duplication")
        TextString = LCase(sht_database.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text)
    End With

    WArray = Split(TextString, " ") 'load array

    If (TextString = "") Then
        MsgBox ("Error: Pls Enter your data")
        End
    End If

    'set column locations for duplicates/no duplicates
    col_no_dup = 1
    col_dup = 2

     With sht_database
        'Print whole array into duplicates column
        .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, col_dup).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(WArray) + IIf(LBound(WArray) = 0, 1, 0)) = Application.Transpose(WArray)
        lrow_no_dup = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col_no_dup).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Loop through array
        For i = LBound(WArray) To UBound(WArray)
            counter = False
            For n = lrow_no_dup To lrow_no_dup + UBound(WArray) 'loop through and check each existing value in the no dup column
                If .Cells(n, col_no_dup).Value = WArray(i) Then
                    counter = True 'account for each occurence
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n
            If counter = False Then 'counter = 0 implies the value doesn't exist in the "No Duplicates" column
                .Cells(lrow_no_dup + j, col_no_dup).Value = WArray(i)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    MsgBox ("Successfully inserted")

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call SplitText
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried sir it works if i type something like this: `financial financial` the no duplicated word displays the (1) financial only and the `with duplicated word` displays `financial financial` but if i enter something like this `my real problem is location because the location` it also displays same value as this. the other duplicated word which is the location displays too in column no duplicated

Comment: I've updated it - this now returns `my real problem is location because the` Is that what's expected?

Comment: Sir tom it works as i expected. This is what i need. Thankyou sir. The reason why i want to keep once only the duplicated word is that i am avoiding the inaccurate counting of most occurence word based on the splitted text that is why i need this kind of output. To eliminate the duplicated word and keep once only. Yes sir this is the answer :) thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist and Dictionaries are ideal when trying to remove duplicates.

### [image]

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim LineUpEntries As Boolean
    Dim TextString As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim listDups As Object, listNoDups As Object
    Set listDups = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
    Set listNoDups = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

    'You need to adjust the Worksheet's name
    TextString = LCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Split").TextBox1.value)

    For Each v In Split(TextString, " ")
        listDups.Add v
        If Not listNoDups.Contains(v) Then
            listNoDups.Add v
        End If
    Next

    'LineUpEntries = True 'Uncomment this line to line up the entries
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duplication")
        If LineUpEntries Then
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Resize(listNoDups.Count)
                .value = Application.Transpose(listNoDups.ToArray)
                FormatRange .Cells
            End With
        Else
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(listNoDups.Count)
                .value = Application.Transpose(listNoDups.ToArray)
                FormatRange .Cells
            End With
        End If
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(listDups.Count)
            .value = Application.Transpose(listDups.ToArray)
            FormatRange .Cells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub FormatRange(Target As Range)
    With Target
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is also very helpful answer with margins to identify per inputs thankyou sir thomas :)

Comment: I think that it would be better if you had the No Duplicated Word
 data start on the same row as the With Duplicated Word
data.

Comment: hmm what lines should i remove in the codes to do that sir ?

Comment: I modified my code to give you the option of lining up the entries.